# How to substitute Expression<Func<T,bool>> into where clause of linq to sql expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to set the following predicate to where clause of linq statement written in expression syntax.

```
Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> condition = p => p.Price > 100;

from purchase in dc.GetTable<Purchase>()
where condition
select ...
```

However, compiler cannot determine which Where to use: IQuaryable<> or IEnumerable<>.
How this problem could be solved without converting linq expression to method chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `where condition` just like that. Either you incorporate the condition in the where clause (where purchase.Price>100) or use the **Where(condition) method call inside** the query expression, like

```
from purchase in dc.GetTable<Purchase>().Where(condition)
select ...
```

This is the way you can combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
where condition.Compile()(purchase);
```

Comment: the OP specifically says `without converting linq expression to method chains`

Comment: I just want to understand the expression syntax not methods chain syntax. (from ... where.. select)

Comment: Didn't get that part, "method chains," check my updated answer.

Comment: This is all fine until run time :), then it throws NotSupportedException
Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: As expected. ;-) I'm not sure if you can really do this using this syntax. What's wrong with the .Where(condition) option?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. I'm just curious about expression syntax. For very complicated queries method chain might be unreadable...

Comment: I understand - but I think you can't combine the two. You can write your complex query using the "friendly" syntax without using the Expressions or you can use Expressions and the Extension Methods.